# gradle error in android studio 2.3.2 while using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase for my android studio application. However I am stuck on this problem and I have tried everything possible to figure it out but I am unable to. Please help.

This is the error:

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find method classpath() for arguments
>   [com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Top-level gradle.build code

```
buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
            }
        }

        allprojects {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
            }
        }

        task clean(type: Delete) {
            delete rootProject.buildDir
        }
```

The other gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mobility.mobilityindia"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    String googleSupportVersion = '25.3.1'
    String googlePlayServicesVersion = '11.0.2'

    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$googleSupportVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$googleSupportVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$googleSupportVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'



}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove these two from your android level `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'   <-- 1.
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'   <-- 2.
    ...
    ...

}
```

Comment: Well I already tried that but then these other errors come up in that case. Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2
  Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2
  Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2
  Error:(36, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2

Comment: Open SDK manager `Tools` -> `Android` -> `SDK Manager` -> `SDK Tools ` -> `Support Repository` -> `Update Google Repository to version 55`

Comment: `SDK Version 11.0.2` deployed on June 29, 2017. I think you don't have that version in your system so you need to download that version there refresh gradle dependency

Comment: yes right. Mine is version 47. I'll update to 55. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, nowadays the actual version is 58, I have the next error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  /home/maria/workspace/android/and-nd-firebase-1.00-starting-point/app/src/debug/google-services.json
  /home/maria/workspace/android/and-nd-firebase-1.00-starting-point/app/google-services.json

Comment: I'm pretty sure the the file is in its place, have you any idea why of my error?

Comment: keep your `.json` inside your project module  folder